# How do you retrieve a cookie value within a view in Laravel 8.x?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to access a cookie within a view, when I try:

```
@forelse(json_decode(request()->cookie('cart'), true) as $order)
```

I get:

> foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

I tried to add it to the view:

```
return response()->view('cart::summary')->withCookie(cookie('cart'));
```

When I check the request debug I can see the cookie is there:

```
cart=%5B%7B%22pizza%22%3A1%2C%22size%22%3A1%2C%22quantity%22%3A1%7D%2C%7B%22pizza%22%3A1%2C%22size%22%3A1%2C%22quantity%22%3A1%7D%5D;
```

How can I retrieve this Cookie within my view?

Comment: Why not use a controller for this? Please don't abuse templates, instead seperate your application according to MVC

Comment: Also, the given string does not look like valid JSON

Comment: I agree that this information should be extracted in the controller and then passed to the view. Keep logic and operations in the template down to a minimum (ideally it should only be concerned with formatting the output).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I couldn't retrieve it because it was always `null`. You have to create an exception for the cookies as Laravel, by default, encrypts them:

```
// app/Http/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php

protected $except = [
    'cart',
];
```